# Journals of applied mathematics with an economics bent?

Tags: reference-request, applications

I'm asking here instead of the economics stackexchange because I'm interested more in the applied mathematics part, instead of just the economics; I'm interested in seeing what new research is being published, and what are the ongoing trends and currents in this area. In that sense, would anyone have interesting journal suggestions for someone interested in applied mathematics, but with a touch of economics, or applied mathematics aimed at economics?

Comment: Hi: The journal of economic dynamics and control might be of use.

Comment: @markleeds thank you for the reference!

Comment: there's probably a journal for game theory  that would have applied mathematics in it.

Comment: @markleeds I'll look it up, thank you!